# Low electronic noise in my audio

Tags: audio-recording, audio, noise

Hello and thankyou in advance for helping me.

I've been having some audio issues for the past few months and I have no idea how to get rid of it. I've tried getting a new mixer and that didn't work. Got new cables and it didn't work. I have no idea what's wrong. I am currently using the following:

- MXL v67i microphone
- Behringer x2222usb mixer
- GLS audio XLR cable
- adobe audition as my DAW

As shown in the picture I've been getting a weird electronic noise that just goes in a straight line. I've also got a problem with low base levels in my audio. I should say that I am new to the audio scene and I am recording at home:

[image]

Here is the audio sound: https://clyp.it/hgxth0bn

Again thank you so much for the help!

**Edit:** Here's what it look likes when everything is unplugged and all of the dials are off:

[image]

Comment: the audio clip is very noisy [as in 'noises off' rather than the noise we're supposed to hear] but the peak frequency is about 450Hz, which isn't any kind of earth hum. Overall, it actually sounds like a recording of a computer in a room, tbh, almost impossible to figure out what else we might be listening for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Noise can be super annoying to find in an audio chain. Yours is relatively short, so it should not take too much effort to find and eradicate!

**ZERO YOUR MIXER**

The sample sounds like you need to check your gain stages. Most budget mixers I've encountered are noisy when channel gain is cranked. If you have headphones, plug them directly into the mixer, and see if the noise is there. If it is, try turning the gain on all channels down fully. Does it go away?

All new sessions should begin by zeroing your mixer:

- Set input gains to minimum (I anally turn all faders down too - it's unnecessary but I find it easier to mix if only the channels in use have faders up!)
- Filters set off
- EQ's set flat
- FX minimized
- Sends turned down

**ELECTRICAL?**

Another common culprit is electrical noise. I'm not hearing 60Hz hum, so unplug everything from the mixer except your headphones, and turn gains and faders all the way down. Do you hear noise then? If not, bring your faders to unity, but keep the gain down still. Should still be silent. While listening, turn gain up on each channel, one by one. Any noise introduced at this point, with nothing plugged in, is either a not so ultra quiet mixer, or electrical noise. Try plugging the mixer in to a different circuit and hear if it goes away.

**THE WEAKEST LINK**

If there is noise only with a microphone plugged into the mixer, try a new mic. Beg, borrow, or steal (not really, but they are cheap to rent) an old dynamic standby like a Shure SM57 or 58. Plug it in and see if you get the same noise. Remember to check your gain stages - too much gain will invariably introduce noise.

**UNITY GAIN**

Learning how to properly set mixer levels will go a long way to preventing extraneous noise in almost all mixer related work. The golden rule is to start by zeroing your mixer, then set levels for each input (we'll use a vocal mic in this instance):

1. Master bus to -0- if meters are POST master fader
2. Bring channel fader to -0-
3. While singing at the loudest you'll be recording into the mic, bring your gain up for that channel until meters read -0- at their peak.

Doing this for each input you'll be recording ensures that each channel is appropriately gained to maximize headroom and minimize noise. It also means you now can easily set levels between each channel (i.e. 'MIX') using only the channel faders.

**SILENCE IS GOLDEN**

I'll never forget the first time I was able to record silence. When DAW's were in their infancy, we didn't have fancy USB/FW interfaces, we had to go in through sound cards, which in all budget cases had really crappy and noisy A/D (SB16 anyone?). Then my first FW MOTU changed all that. OK, get off my lawn!

Comment: Thanks alot for your response! When I turn everything down on my mixer and unplug everything but the headphones I still get the noise. I even tried unplugging from the outlet. I'll edit the above post to show you what it looks like when the mix board is unplugged. Thank you so much for your help and thank you for your insights. I usually just leave all the valves halfway but from now on I'll adjust it after each time : )

Comment: It reads like you have two issues - noise in the mixer via headphones by itself, and the computer is picking up noise as well, even with the mixer unplugged from the computer. If that's the case, it may be your AC needs conditioning. I wouldn't say it's a ground loop as that's usually very audible 60Hz hum, but instead from something plugged into the same circuit (or bad wires/switch somewhere). Any appliances on the circuit your computer and mixer are on? Try moving the mixer to a different circuit and see if the noise is still there - if not, you've found your culprit!

Comment: I moved my mixer to my downstairs outlet and it worked without noise. Thank you so much for your help man!

Answer (score 0):

What computer are you using? I used to get terrible groundloop issues when using my laptop and having the PSU plugged in at the same time.

I would recommend connecting your audio gear (i.e. mixer) to a different power supply/socket than the computer.

From what I can see from your specs the Behringer is the weakest link in your chain at the minute. If you've got the budget then it may be worth investing in a better quality audio interface.

Unfortunately I could not hear your example (network issues at my end, don't worry), once I get a chance to have a proper listen I might be able to give you a more thorough analysis.